# Add extra interface property to a Component if it is used as children

Tags: typescript, jsx, typescript-generics, tsc

I'm using TypeScript in JSX syntax *without* using React (or any other similar library). For `jsxFactory`, I'm using my own factory.

This is the simplest version of what I want:

```
<Panel>
  <Banner text="FREE OFFER" align="left" />
</Panel>
```

The `align` property is `required` *only* when the `Banner` is placed inside `Panel`.

`Banner` can be used outside of a `Panel`, but in that case using `align` property should throw an error.

I want it to happen during compile time.

I've already tried [this on typescriptlang playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=1&module=1&ssl=37&ssc=40&pln=37&pc=52#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEBzCB7ARlC8DeBYAUPEfAHZQC2IAzgA5RgIBSAygBo4HFfwCWJALiBgAzeggCiEEJQEBhABY8IwOCQCC-fjB5oAroJzwwi5aoBcOAL4BueJc7F7%20JwT6CRY%20ACEoJEkIBJASFRBg5CYn4efikLKi0%20RAAaByJBAA9%20OISSRAIXfEgoKipvX38YAB4AFXgQTJASYFKfP0DgjzCAXjK2mCD3UJAAPiI8CKIwFBJ4mF0wfhQYAAoaGBQaKgtqgEpw7mIAekPUu3yCVw6h%20DUIHkQSGX4BkM96wSaW8vbBz3GuTD3EgWABEs0SIPO%20DcrzCAAVfCAIC9Ogh-sQoMAAsBstpcikJkYTCpGhZWhVKrcgU8UUNRsd4AEAOTkeBaACeiTZKHgdBKbPkCCpDxpV08iwFCHJQiQjSEPDAUKK-IR-iw6Mm01m80WKzWGy28FVSNpYj2Gu4x1OTgKDIC8AA7r5%20AKeKUJfx5OsHUYUOQaEoEEJ1jAkvBiuG7g9eKUSCgXXxJb0KqaGAQpjMXZjpTB4D1Kjm2dEpF0QUFQDRGqABMmhCC2e9S4J4vXAQ9S1JhPx64dhtYLvg7ZGqDynTXPW7uQLveGvn0Y-A0CAuboqCBgLPw0SlCSSPAUMIjYiIASGb4N8IlgKoC77WOXZ6EG29xKl-A4ABHXQ8ODAAB06Zai6dBqoWPTLJUxpYJi2KlgAjCCwynAW3y5lEMQgKW5YgJWTSNC6Ob1hk-BNtQ3bwL2BCVIcUHDDs-b4AO9Q0EsLqgKIugQC62BHmqYaFjYBBAA).

```
declare global {
    namespace JSX {
        interface ElementChildrenAttribute { children: {}; }
    }
}

interface BannerInterface {
    title: string,
    text: string
}

class Banner<T extends BannerInterface = BannerInterface>  {
    constructor(props: T) {
        //
    }
}

interface AlignmentInterface extends BannerInterface {
    align: string
}
interface PanelInterface {
    adId: string,
    children: Banner<AlignmentInterface> // I'm trying to pass the AlignmentInterface to the Banner generic
}
class Panel {
    constructor(props: PanelInterface) {
        //
    }
}

// I want this to throw compile error, as align is not in the BannerInterface
const adBanner = <Banner title="Independent Banner" text="test" align="left" />;

// I also want this to throw as Banner is being used as a children of Panel,
// and for that I want the align prop to be required.
const panelBanner = (<Panel adId="1">
                        <Banner title="Banner inside Panel" text="test" />
                     </Panel>);


export default { Panel, Banner };
```

Comment: I'd suggest a higher-order type, switch it around, something like `children: Aligned<Banner>`. It's a bit weird to say `Banner` can only accept `align` when it's inside `Panel` at the type level, because what if you assign `const MyBanner = () => <Banner ... />` then render *that* in a panel?

Comment: Hi @jonrsharpe, thanks for your response. I get your point. For my use-case, I also have a run-time validation. So, if a `Banner` is dynamically added inside a `Panel` I'm throwing run-time exception, which is good enough.

But I want the JSX validation during compile-time (and VS code editing suggestions) when it's typed as a nested template.

Also, if I don't use JSX, and just use `new Panel(...children: new Banner())` - in that case I also want the TS validation of the children to have `align` in Banner.

Thanks

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I think I just solved it by passing the generic from JSX syntax like `<Panel< AlignmentInterface> title="" text="" align="">`. It looks bit odd, but works! Thanks for your hints. :-)